# Is there a way to upgrade Kentico CMS version 7 to Kentico CMS version 9?

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, kentico

Are there any methods or ways to upgrade Kentico CMS version 7 to Kentico CMS version 9 without breaking any custom(functions, pages....)? 
or Do I need to upgrade Kentico CMS version 7 to Kentico CMS version 8 then Kentico CMS version 8 to Kentico CMS version 9?

I am trying to upgrade Kentico 7.0 to Kentico 8.0 and following the Auto upgrade instructions, however; I'm facing problem with "Connection Time out variable" on update database section. What's more, It takes hours and never ends.

Comment: You have to upgrade subsequently from 7.0 to 8.0, 8.1 and 8.2 to be able to upgrade to version 9.0. There's no way around it. Can you post more details about the error you are getting?

Comment: I am stuck at Krntico Upgrade Utility mode(Update SQL script) after I run Upgrade_7_0_8_0.exe. It was an auto upgrade.

Thank you for your answer. I think topic is on hold. And I got recommended to use SUper User instead.

Comment: Erro message: 

Stack Trace: 
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Hotfix.HotfixHelper.RunSQLScript(String fileName, String connString, String defaultUICulture, IMessageLog messageLog)

Comment: Assuming you have an actual database backup AND have not made any direct database changes you should be able to run the SQL script again on it's own after the database has been restored to its original state.  Seems your error message is pretty generic, if you have specifics about that error message please post them.  You should also ensure the user running that SQL script has administrative permissions to that database.

Comment: Thanks again, I will try reload my backup and go throw SQL update manually.
I am trying to find the specific error in the logs, however; there aren't any specific errors. For permissions, I ran Upgrade_7_0_8_0.exe as administrator and in database connection(web.config), configured user is db_owner.

Comment: If you run it again, does it fail at a particular SQL script? Is the utility able to execute any other scripts before it fails (or does it fail at the first one)?

Comment: I had it run manually in SQL Server Management Studio. Seem it took a while to finish but it's fine. But the site still fail, seem I need to manually check new api or customs code again.
Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

The required steps to perform your upgrade are:

- v7 to v8
- v8 to v8.1
- v8.1 to v8.2
- v8.2 to v9

At each point, you will need to fix any custom code API changes you've written and run the website.  This is very important to run the website after each upgrade, this completes the upgrade process.  Also at each point, be sure to clear your cache.

Some good references are:

- [API Changes](http://devnet.kentico.com/documentation/api-changes/kentico-9)
- [Upgrade to v8](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Upgrading+Kentico+7+to+8)
- [Upgrade to v8.1](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/Upgrading+to+Kentico+8.1)
- [Upgrade to v8.2](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Upgrading+to+Kentico+8.2)
- [Upgrade to v9](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Upgrading+to+Kentico+9)

Comment: Appreciate your help, I am more cleared about the upgrading process.